# OrientDB Indexes are not used

Tags: orientdb

I have a problem.... here is a part of sample query:

select * from tablename WHERE (id = "some4294-0643-4eaa-a262-7479c1859860" OR code = "some4294-0643-4eaa-a262-7479c1859860")
and deleted is null and blablablabla...>

And there are 2 indexes on this table: id and code.
If I'm querying tablename this way, indexes are not used.

In other query: select from (select * from tablename WHERE (id = "some4294-0643-4eaa-a262-7479c1859860" OR code = "some4294-0643-4eaa-a262-7479c1859860"))
where deleted is null and blablablabla...>

Indexes are used.

problem is my query is even more complex..... and I don't really want to deal with select in select.... but I really wish indexes to be used...

Is there any way to build index for 1st statement?

Comment: which version of OrientDB?

Comment: right now its OrientDB version : 2.1.13, but I had similar problem with other 2.x releases.... it seems like brackets prevent indexes from being used.... probably its bug, but may be I'm doing something wrong....

Comment: Hi @ivp, I tried your case and I got your same results. Are you the author of [this](https://github.com/orientechnologies/orientdb/issues/6014) issue ?

Comment: Yep.... It seems like I'll have to deal with it... I reworked my query builder to handle "or" statements the way luigidellaquila suggested... (actually it worked that way.... I just wanted to make my query builder to generate something more pretty).... queries looks really ugly, but Indexes are used and for now its fast enough.... I really hope this approach not going to turn into something bad in future...

Comment: We are already working at this issue and will be resolved in v3.0